# NetBeans IDE 8.2 + XDebug + Wampserver 3.4.1 not working

Tags: php, wamp, xdebug, netbeans-8

I am an IT professional and 30+ years programmer (Visual Studio + SQL et al.), but NOT a professional web developer. I developed a personal website (html+php+javascript+mysql) for a worthy cause in my spare time, so please bear with me. The website is running locally as well as on a web hosting site.

Now my problem: Getting tired of debugging PHP code with

```
print $variable.'<br />';
```

I recently installed Wampserver 3.4.1 and NetBeans IDE 8.2 on my Windows 7 x64 computer, mainly for debugging purposes, but the debugging part is not working.

The contents of section [xdebug] in file **E:\Wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.35\bin\php.ini** is:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="E:/Wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable = Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "E:/Wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars= 0
xdebug.remote_log = "E:/Wamp64/logs/xdebug_log.txt"
```

The messages I get are:

(Mozilla Firefox)

**Not Found**

The requested URL /www/index.php was not found on this server.

*Apache/2.4.35 (Win64) PHP/7.2.10 Server at localhost Port 80*

(Netbeans IDE)

*Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)*.

What is wrong ?

[Added]

[image]

Another piece of info:

The project folder structure is

index.php located in E:/Wamp64/www/

All other files (php, javascript, css, pictures) each in a corresponding subfolder of the above folder. The structure is exactly the same on the production server (hosting server). I guess it's the most common way to organize website resources.

The Project folder is in another place because I didn't want Netbeans's own files to be mixed with the files of the website.

**$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** for the local website (correctly) returns "E:/Wamp64/www" (without quotes).

Comment: In your php.ini file, did you specify a zend_extension for the xdebug.so file that you get when you install xdebug on the server?  When you install with PECL, you should see a final message that tells you the location of your *.so file.  You then need to add it as a zend_extension

Also, it sounds like you have an issue with connecting to the web server itself.  Is your public dir within www/?  Otherwise, you shouldn't prefix the url with www/.  If your webroot is /var/www/html/ (or wherever) and your index.php is within that folder, just go to localhost:80/index.php

Comment: @cchoe1 i think he mentioned it `zend_extension="E:/Wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"`

Comment: @Mikey you can use this wizard https://xdebug.org/wizard.php. It may help you.

Comment: @cchoe (1) I didn't install XDebug, it is included in the wampserver 3 package. I just used XDebug's "Tailored Installation Instructions" to tell me how I should configure Apache. The values for xdebug configuration already were in te php.ini file or I googled them. (2) My webroot is /www, i.e. e:\wamp64\www\, My index.php file is located there.

Comment: @Amit Ray Yes, I already used that. Thanks.

Comment: @Mikey sorry I'm a little less familiar with Windows and didn't realize the .dll was the .so equivalent.  So it sounds like everything should be set up properly.  You're saying on Firefox, going to localhost/index.php works fine?  I'm not sure if this is necessary for Windows, but I always specify ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1 at the end of my URLs when working on my mac.

Comment: @All I don't understand why **Netbeans IDE** tries to find my index.php in localhost/www/ instead of just localhost/. When trying to debug, Firefox Developer Edition is launched (although normal Firefox is already running) and the address bar (?) is: **http://localhost/www/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug**. Maybe my Netbeans Project properties need some changes ?

Comment: @Mikey Yes, you are correct on that. Sadly I cannot help with this as I'm not NetBeans user (I'm using PhpStorm). You may need to look at your deployment settings (in IDE) or a place where you specify you project web URL. Another idea: launch debugger manually in IDE (let it start listening to incoming Xdebug requests) and then just paste proper URL in browser manually (without extra `www/` part). You need to first fix your `www/` part somehow and  then move to possible debug settings etc.

Comment: @Mikey If you can show your setup screenshots, we may guess where to change stuff... Other than that -- please look for and follow NetBeans specific tutorials/manuals about deployment and debugging. (I may suggest PhpStorm ones .. but it's quite irrelevant to your situation as it's all may work completely different in NetBeans...)

Comment: @LazyOne I added the screenshot for the Netbeans Project Properties page. From your comment above the last: How do I launch the debugger manually... ? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: As @LazyOne suggested and I finally understood how to do it (...), I manually deleted the /www and STARTED DEBUGGING. Also, Tools/Options/Debugging should be checked using some of the input from here https://articlebin.michaelmilette.com/making-xdebug-work-with-netbeans-on-windows/. I'll play around a bit, but now I can really use the debugging functionality in NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

As some of you suggested, you can manually rewrite the link in the browser eliminating the /www bit and, if the Debugging Options (Tools/Options/Debugging) in NetBeans IDE 8.2 are correctly set (they are, by default), debugging works. This link is also useful: https://articlebin.michaelmilette.com/making-xdebug-work-with-netbeans-on-windows/

Until I'll discover why the /www is added by NetBeans, this solution will do - quite well, actually.